# "Gun an engine" vs. "Rev an engine"

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms, north-american-english

> The driver of the van brakes sharply at every red light or junction and **guns the engine** when we move off. I begin to sweat—travelling sideways isn't helping.
>    <sub>*[Apple Tree Yard](http://www.any-read.com/read/Apple_Tree_Yard/Chapter_17.html)*</sub>

"To gun the engine" is a new expression for me. I would have said the driver "revs the engine" but because the author, Louise Doughty is British, it must be well known in the UK. However, I have a feeling it's a recent coinage.

Is there a difference between *rev* and *gun* an engine? Can I say: "I gunned my car"?
OR "He gunned the vehicle as if his life depended on it"? Do you only *gun* an engine?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gunning Verb(with object) 10. to cause (an engine, vehicle, aircraft, etc.) to increase in speed very quickly by increasing the supply of fuel. And http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rev.

Comment: I'm British and have **never heard** the term 'gun' with reference to an engine. Some people here do **rev** their engines, when stationary.

Comment: Gun an engine (n.); the sense of "to accelerate an engine" is from 1930, from earlier phrase to give (something) the gun. Etymonline.

Comment: Both my Mum and Dad (born 1920's UK) knew and used this (... *gunning his engine ...*)

Comment: When you add a little psychology to the etymology you come to realize that being a pedestrian in America is not without its risks.

Comment: @LittleEva so you would be afraid if I were to start *rifling* through papers?

Comment: +1 @Digital Chris - I was so glad when email came along and I could avoid the PO. :-))

Comment: I'm British and I've seen it many times in fiction; usually of the thriller variety, e.g. "With a surge of adrenaline she lodged the pistol between the dashboard and the windscreen and gunned the engine. The truck bucked, jolted, and surged forward."

Comment: @Phil M Jones certainly it has a more dramatic edge to it. Wonder if the authors *tend* to be fairly young and American

Comment: In the US, to "rev" an engine would only apply to when it was not "under load".

Comment: Not gun-runners.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the US we usually "*rev*" a motor that's *idling* or in *neutral*, while reserving the term "***gun***" for rapidly accelerating the engine of a vehicle *in gear* to significantly increase speed, as you describe in your example. Ps: your driver reminds me of my dad!

**Edit**: I looked for supporting references but couldn't find any that recognize the distinctions I indicated. These different usages are actual in *vernacular* AmE though probably not recognized by some, and certainly not absolute. One could use these terms interchangeably and be clearly understood. I wouldn't personally, but hey, I hang out here, with a more *discriminating* crowd!

Ps: oh yeah, in America we not only love to hold a ***gun***, and to fire ***guns***, we also like to use the word ***gun***, as often as possible, hence, we ***gun*** our engines.

Here is a reference from a car fanatics forum illustrating my contention that a subtle distinction does exist between revving an engine and gunning a motor vehicle:

> **TOMCAT104**
>
> Whereas turbo's engine low-end torque might be more useful in daily driving situations (and since BMW seems to have reduce the turbo's lag to insignificance), it might have an advantage over the n.a in that respect. True, **turbos cannot replace the joy of reving your engine high and gunning it**, but in practice for most daily driving situations, would a turbo be actually a more suitable engine?
>
> from [**BIMMERFORUMS**](http://www.bimmerforums.com/forum/showthread.php?1722832-Will-BMW-produce-another-naturally-aspirated-I6-or-is-N52-53-the-end/page2)
>
> **GUN** *verb* (used with object), ***gunned***, ***gunning***.
>
> **10**. to cause (an engine, vehicle, aircraft, etc.) to increase in speed very quickly by increasing the supply of fuel.
>
> [**Dictionary.com**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gunning)
>
> **rev** (v.) 1916, from earlier noun (1901), **shortening of** ***revolution***, in reference to the internal combustion engine. Related: Revved; revving.
>
> **gun** (v.) " to shoot with a gun," 1620s, from gun (n.); the sense of "***to accelerate an engine***" is from 1930, from earlier phrase to give (something) the gun. Related: Gunned; gunning.
>
> [**The Online Etymology Dictionary**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gun&searchmode=or)

Comment: Gun an engine, an AmE expression: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guns+his+engine%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cguns+his+engine%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cguns%20his%20engine%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Give it (her) the gun, is a related idiomatic expression:
Fig. to make a motor or engine run faster; to rev up an engine. (The her is often pronounced "er.") Bill: How fast will this thing go? Bob: I'll give it the gun and see. Hurry up, driver. Give 'er the gun. I've got to get there immediately.http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Give+her+the+gun

Comment: I'll agree with you ... if you revved the engine while it was idling, it wouldn't be *gunning* it.

Comment: @PeterShor - I'll disagree with you ... you can gun an engine (with the clutch disengaged so the _engine_ moves faster internally - revs) or you can gun a car (with the clutch engaged so the _car_ moves faster). You can also thrash them, cane them, hammer them, horse them and race them.

Comment: @Frank - I didn't claim these distinctions were absolutes or codified, I said the opposite. But I know how these expressions are most often employed in the vernacular, too, and there is a subtle distinction.

Comment: I was disagreeing (in the mildest possible way) with Peter Shor. I do agree that _revving_ is probably more commonly used for when the clutch is disengaged simply because the engine can rev-up more quickly.

Comment: @Josh61 yes but https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=revs+the+engine%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crevs+the+engine%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crevs%20the%20engine%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crevs%20the%20engine%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0 and even more interestingly https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=revs+his+engine%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crevs+his+engine%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crevs%20his%20engine%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: you can't gun a car, but you can "gun it!" where *it* refers to the engine.

Comment: @sgroves - well, if you look at the reference I posted from BIMMER, when TOMCAT104 says, "reving [sic] your engine high and gunning it", **it** refers to something other than the engine, and I can only assume that "**it**" refers to the car.

Comment: @littleeva perhaps by extension, yes. you would never say "gun the car" though.

Comment: I would suggest that "gunning" the engine involves increasing its speed with the intention that that speed will be transferred to the wheels *before it is allowed to subside*, while revving the engine generally involves running its speed up and then back down without ever putting a vehicle into gear.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I would also add that you can rev the engine slowly, but you cannot "gun it" slowly.

Comment: @LittleEva In the phrase "reving your engine high and gunning it" I actually *am* reading 'it' as referring to the engine.

Comment: @DCShannon - well for my part I interpreted the meaning as, "revving the engine then gunning the car," but maybe I misinterpreted, maybe you're right.

Comment: This is coherent with the forward motion at speed senses of both _gun_ the noun and _gun_ the verb. That's the way things work with metaphors. Especially motion metaphors; we use a lot of them.